# Can we put an SPWeb object into a SPSite object?

Tags: spsite

This is possible:

```
  using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].Url))
```

Is this possible?:

```
 using (SPSite site = new SPSite(SPContext.Current.Site.WebApplication.Sites[0].RootWeb.Url))
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes this will also work, but you are not putting an SPWeb object into SPSite object.. Instead you are just using the Url to instantiate a new SPSite object

In most of the cases SPSite.Url and SPSite.RootWeb.Url return same Url.. As you have already asked it here [What is difference between SPSite.Url and SPSite.RootWeb.Url](https://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/94960/what-is-difference-between-spsite-url-and-spsite-rootweb-url)